# Send single item of list from view to controller via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view composed of a list of users:

```
 @model List<LabelPrinting.Models.UserModel>
```

and I put these into a JavaScript object:

```
 users = function () { return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) }();
```

I then load a jQuery accordion with the values for each.  I then choose to print avery labels for a particular user in the list and set a value.  I'm trying to send only that particular user to the controller and am getting a null values for of the user properties:

```
 function PrintAveryLabel(but) {
    var id = but.id.substring(9);
    var $rad = $(but).closest('tr').siblings().find('.radLabelOther');
    if (($rad).is(':checked')) {
        var $txtr = $rad.closest('tr').siblings().find('.classRows');
        var $txtc = $rad.closest('tr').siblings().find('.classCols');
        if ($txtr.val() === "0" || $txtc.val() === "0") {
            $("#lblError").text("You have have not selected the rows and columns for the labels.");
            $("#MessageDialog").dialog({ title: "Select Rows/Columns" });
            $("#MessageDialog").dialog("open");
            return false;
        }
    }
    var data = findUser(id);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: { pat: data },
        url: '@Url.Action("PrintUserLabels")'
    });
}
```

The findUser function simply picks the entry in the list that matches the ID.

```
 function findUser(id) {
    var data;
    for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        if (users[i].UserId === parseInt(id)) {
            data = users[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

My controller action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PrintUserLabels(UserModel pat)
    {
        string retval = "";
        if (pat.PrintLabel)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Label", new { user = pat });
        }
        else
        {
            retval = "ERROR - you must make a selection";
            Exception e = new Exception(retval);
            HandleErrorInfo info = new HandleErrorInfo(e, "DYMO", "PrintPatientLabels");
            return RedirectToAction("Error", info);
        }
    }
```

The label action is tried and true but I get a null user model.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what data is returned by `findUser(id)`? add that to your question

Comment: @DLeh - added that function, although all it does is find the person in the array and return it.

Comment: then show what the type of a user is, whats the data you're actually trying to send look like? because that's where the problem is happening

Comment: Your model is a collection. Inspect the value of `users` and you will see that the names have indexers. You cannot post back indexed objects to a method expecting only one object.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - if I post the entire form into an action that is the entire list of user model then I have to iterate through each one to find the one I want to print.  This works but it just seems silly to post the entire list when I only need one.  I'm trying the post a single model which was collected when the page was initialized, and it contains all of the values for each user.

Comment: It seems just as silly to serialize your model to JSON. You already have the `id` of the `UserModel` you need (at least I assume that's what `var id = but.id.substring(9);` is) so just post back the `id` (make you method `public ActionResult PrintUserLabels(int id)` and get the associated `UserModel`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - that is an idea.  But I have several other values that are part of the model that I set in the view that I need.  So I guess I could include each one of those to do it.  I will try that.

Comment: Then just construct the data your want to return - `data: { id: id, anotherProperty: anotherValue, etc }` but the better approach is to just add the values you need as `data-` attributes of the button and get them using `var id = $(this).data('id');` etc

Comment: Also your POST method has `return RedirectToAction(...)`. Your making an ajax call and ajax calls stay on the same page (they never redirect) so that code makes no sense.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - the action constructs a document with iTextSharp (PDF) and creates entries for printing on Avery labels and sends the result with Response.ContentType = "pdf/application";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=user_labels.pdf");
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);